# What created the first ribosome

Tags: evolution, proteins, molecular-evolution

If a ribosome is made of protein, yet is used in protein sysnthesis, what created the first ribosome?

What created the ribosomal RNA?

Comment: This question has been asked before in several variations and has several detailed answers as I recall. I’m away at the moment with only my phone. Perhaps someone else could look up the actual question to mark it a duplicate.

Comment: @David yes, there are similar questions about [DNA and DNA polymerase](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/42968/3340) and [ATP synthase](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/5162/3340). I didn't mark this as a dupe of them because it could be argued that ribosomes are different. However, we can mark all subsequent questions on this topic as a dupe of this one or the others

Comment: @WYSIWYG I’ll have a look when I get back this weekend. It would be good to have one or two definitive questions (the ribosome may require its own) with a selection of comprehensive answers. I have my own contributions to make, but would rather do so in a coordinated manner. Perhaps the way to handle it would be on meta.

Comment: @WYSIWYG — Found the previous question —  almost exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the "chichen and the egg" quesitons about early origins of life. The answer is: **we don't know**. There is a [RNA world hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_world) which suggests that RNAs were the primary versatile biomolecules before proteins. This idea stems from the fact that there are self-replicating RNAs and ribozymes (RNA-based enzymes). Also, the fact that the catalytic center  ([peptidyl transferase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peptidyl_transferase)) of the ribosome is RNA, is also used in support of the the RNA world. However, this is still an idea and we cannot conclusively say that an RNA-world existed.

Comment: As the question is clearly a duplicate you might wish to migrate your answer to the original. I am considering writing a second answer (I already included a devil's advocate one) because I do not feel the current RNA world answer there is adequate.