# What came first: the ribosome in which RNA is read, or the RNA to encode for the ribosome proteins?

Tags: evolution, dna, proteins, ribosome, abiogenesis

It's a bit like the chicken-and-egg problem. Ribosomes need proteins because they are partially made of them. Where can they get their proteins? They read the base sequence in mRNA entering them, assemble the amino acids, and spit out the proteins. The problem though is that the proteins needed for the ribosome need a ribosome in the first place.

I realize that it's a highly simplified picture I paint here, but I think its clear what I mean. Did proteins existed before RNA/DNA? Amino acids were created in a lab-soup already many decades ago, back in the previous century, and probably the same holds for RNA-kind of (small) structures. Did one of them come first? Did protein primordial life took advantage of self-replicating structures capable of storing information about proteins, or did the self-replicating structures took advantage of the primordial protein life to facilitate replication?

Comment: I suggest — and indeed this list requires — that you do a little reading on this topic, which was first raised over 60 years ago. Of course, we do not (can not) know that answer, but we do know that the ribosomal peptidyl transferase resides in the ribosomal RNA, so it is possible (likely?) that the original ribosome lacked protein, simplifying the question a little.

Comment: @David Thanks. That would simplify things. But what should be called life then? Proteins (which I assume were present), or self-replicating RNA-like stuff?

Comment: This question has also been asked several times before: see https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/80603/what-created-the-first-ribosome